# Does csv.DicReader() return a dictionary object?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

While I am trying to use `csv.DictReader()` to transfer a **CSV** file to a dictionary, like this:

```
csv_file = open(input_file, "r")
data = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

However, I cannot apply any dictionary methods into `data`.

Thus, I print the type of `data`.

```
print(type(data))
```

and find the type is:

```
<class 'csv.DictReader'>
```

So does `csv.DictReader()` really return a dictionary object? How can I get a dictionary object from **CSV**?

My **CSV** file looks like this:

```
[['play', 'weather', 'temperature'], ['yes', 'sunny', '77'], ['no', 'rainny', '60'], ['yes', 'windy', '70'],...]
```

Actually, I do not have a expected output. I just want to store these value for my further calculation.

**Edit (as per comment):** The output could be two parts. The first one is the headers of the csv file, such as `['play', 'weather', 'temperature']` . The second one can be this: `[['yes', 'sunny', '77'], ['no', 'rainny', '60'], ['yes', 'windy', '70']...]`

Comment: Could you maybe show us what your csv file looks like and what kind of dictionary you want to get as output?

Comment: Given your example, what do you want your desired dictionary to look like?

Comment: I have added the file. But basically, I don't know which way is the best way to store it.  @jpp

Comment: @Aran-FeyI have added the file. But basically, I don't know which way is the best way to store it.

Comment: What you have is essentially a list of dicts. So converting it to a single dict doesnt seem to make a a lot of sense. What would the keys be? The line numbers. By simply calling `list(data)`, you will get a list of `OrderedDict`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry I am fresh in Python. The output could be two parts. The first one is the headers of the csv file, such as  ['play', 'weather', 'temperature'] . The second one can be this: [['yes', 'sunny', '77'], ['no', 'rainny', '60'], ['yes', 'windy', '70']...]

Comment: If you look to store for calculations than will suggest to look for pandas dataframe instead of dict ...

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks a lot!

Comment: @n1tk Exactly. But due to some special requirements, I cannot use pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### csv.reader

Given your desired output, you do not need to use `dict` or, consequently, `csv.DictReader`. Instead, just use `csv.reader`, which returns an iterator. Then use `next` and `list` to extract headers and data respectively:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

x = StringIO("""play,weather,temperature
yes,sunny,77
no,rainy,60
yes,windy,70""")

# replace x with open('file.csv', 'r')
with x as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    headers = next(reader)  # get headers from first row
    data = list(reader)     # exhaust iterator from second row onwards
```

The result is a list of headers, and a list of lists for data:

```
print(headers)

['play', 'weather', 'temperature']

print(data)

[['yes', 'sunny', '77'],
 ['no', 'rainy', '60'],
 ['yes', 'windy', '70']]
```

#### pandas

If you are willing to use a 3rd party library, Pandas may be a better option as it handles type conversion and indexing more conveniently:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

The result is a `pd.DataFrame` object:

```
print(df)

  play weather  temperature
0  yes   sunny           77
1   no   rainy           60
2  yes   windy           70

print(type(df))

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

`DictReader` returns a file-like object.  It still reads the data from the csv file in one row at a time, but the returned rows are ordered dictionaries instead of lists.

If your files is:

```
play,weather,temperature
yes,sunny,77
no,rainny,60
yes,windy,70
```

Then you can use `DictReader` in the following way:

```
with open('path/to/file.csv') as fp:
    header = fp.readline().strip().split(',')
    dreader = DictReader(fp, header)
    data = list(dreader)
```

In this case, `data` will be a list of `OrderedDict` objects with the mapping from the headers to each item in the row.

```
data
#returns:
[OrderedDict([('play', 'yes'), ('weather', 'sunny'), ('temperature', '77')]),
 OrderedDict([('play', 'no'), ('weather', 'rainny'), ('temperature', '60')]),
 OrderedDict([('play', 'yes'), ('weather', 'windy'), ('temperature', '70')])]
```